Third-Party Software, Desktop/WPF and Docker Containers
I'm trying to containerize an app i developed which uses nugets and third party dll's (that depends from some desktop frameworks like WPF, WindowsForms, etc... but that i'm not using in the method i call). However everytime i try to run the application it doesn't load the DLL from the third party.
I'm trying to containerize an application i'm currently work on, but this app has some particularities.
It is a solution composed by two projects. The csproj from the main program is like this:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <Optimize>False</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <Optimize>False</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="ThirdPartyDLL" Version="10.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility" Version="8.0.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

It uses some third-party dlls from which i have few information. About the dependencies it has i have it:

Assembly ThirdPartDLL, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=
Assembly references:
mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=
System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=
WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=
PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=
PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=
System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=
WindowsFormsIntegration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=
System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=
System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=
System.Xaml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=
System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=
Module references:
KERNEL32.dll

In my program, i'm not using any method that explicitly request for displayin, UI events/interactions, etc... I'm using just methods that i think are about processing algorithms. Altougth my app didn't start and always fails with the error  IOFileNotFound: can't find or load. In the case, if i didn't put the file in the output folder it will print just "not found" so i think this error is being raised by "not able to load the file". The dockerfile i'm currently using is this:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./*.config ./

RUN powershell -Command " \
    $version = '0.1.25'; \
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://github.com/Microsoft/artifacts credprovider/releases/download/v$version/Microsoft.NuGet.CredentialProvider.tar.gz -OutFile Microsoft.NuGet.CredentialProvider.tar.gz; \
    $credProviderDir = \"$env:LOCALAPPDATA\\MicrosoftCredentialProvider\"; \
    $nugetPluginDir = \"$env:USERPROFILE\\.nuget\\plugins\"; \
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $credProviderDir; \
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $nugetPluginDir; \
    tar -xf Microsoft.NuGet.CredentialProvider.tar.gz -C $credProviderDir; \
    Copy-Item -Path \"$credProviderDir\\*\" -Destination $nugetPluginDir -Recurse -Force; \
    Remove-Item -Force Microsoft.NuGet.CredentialProvider.tar.gz"

COPY CloudTest1/*.sln ./CloudTest1/
COPY CloudTest1/. ./CloudTest1/
COPY Collision/. ./Collision/

RUN dotnet nuget locals all --clear
RUN dotnet restore CloudTest1/Solution.sln --force

RUN dotnet publish CloudTest1/Solution.sln -c Release --no-restore

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2019

RUN dism.exe /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:NetFX4 /NoRestart
RUN dism.exe /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:WCF-Services45 /NoRestart


SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]
RUN if not exist C:\TEMP mkdir C:\TEMP

ADD https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/d0849e66-227d-40f7-8f7b-c3f7dfe51f43/37f8a04ab7ff94db7f20d3c598dc4d74/windowsdesktop-runtime-6.0.29-win-x64.exe C:/TEMP/dotnet-desktop-installer.exe

RUN C:/TEMP/dotnet-desktop-installer.exe /install /quiet /norestart
SHELL ["powershell", "-command"]

RUN Remove-Item -Path C:\TEMP\dotnet-desktop-installer.exe -Force

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
COPY --from=build-env /app/ ./TESTE/
COPY License/. ./`
COPY Resources/. /app/Resources

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Solution.dll"]


Do you have any tips about how i can solve this, or it's just impossible to do it due to the WPF dependence even it is not being used by any method i'm calling in my app? Thanks in advance!

Edit nº1: To complete the information that Andy ask about the main .csproj i will add it here. Yet, about this topic, the "logic think" is that UI-frameworks aren't made to be run in containers, and if my app use them, i should re-design. However, here i'm working with a third-party dll that i can't manipulate, so it will always depend on these kind of frameworks. What i was thinking to do, is to install all the needed frameworks in the container, to make them "available", so it can load my app and load all its dependencies. Then, during execution, they will not be used, because i'm not using the methods that need them.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup 
Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <Optimize>False</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup 
Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <Optimize>False</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="ThirdPartydll" Version="10.0.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


Can we get more specifics about the error you are encountering?  File not found, ok, but during which operation?  Which file was not found?  Where did it look for the file?  Did you verify that the file was included in the container at the right spot?  Or is it that you don't understand where the files should be in the first place?

Sure. The error is this one Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'ThirdPartydll, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxx'. The system cannot find the file specified. It fails to start the program, it didn't enter the main method, it's in while loading and doing set up to all the dependencies, from my understanding. Yeah, i ran docker cp and all needed files are placed in the rigth place. Plus the .exe and .dll built through dockerfile runs well in my computer

Side note:  docker cp puts files in a running container, not an image.  Also, I see you running dotnet Solution.dll, not an exe.

After get the image, i use docker create to obtain a container, and then i use docker cp to check the app folder and it's where i confirm all the needed dlls are there. I already tried both, to run .dll and the .exe altougth both result in the same error. As i showed in the first code block, this external dll depends in some frameworks (e.g Forms) that aren't present in the images available, since UI doesn't make sense to exist in containers. However, i'm only running method from this dll that doesn't use these frameworks, that's why i was hoping that exists a way to run it in a container

Please show us your entry point csproj. I've never tried to run a Wpf app in a container and I'm doubtful it'd even work. I think if you start up any app then it'll attempt to load it's dependencies.

@Andy i edited the post with some more information and the .csproj. Thanks in advance!
